# Do anyone know how to use gdi+ to open a multi-page icon image file?

Tags: icons, gdi+

I've tried searching the keyword "gdi+ " and "multi page icon" on internet for long time, but failed to get a satisfied answer, can anybody help me?

Comment: I tried searching for just the keyword "multi page icon" on the Internet because I don't know what it is, and I can't find much of anything about it. Are you talking about an ICO file that contains multiple sizes and bit depths of icons?

Answer (score 0):

you can use icofx software to edit,create icons(.ico) that contains multiple size and color depths.

Also icofx is freeware.

http://icofx.ro/